# Dynamic 2-dimension array in C

Tags: c

Hello I've never used dynamics 2-dimension array in C, so I need your help. 
How can I build 2-dimension array with allocating memory?

I thought about something like this :

```
int ** dynamic_allocate_array(int n, int m) {
    int **A = (int **) malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = (int *) malloc (m*sizeof(int));
    }
    return A;
}
```

But my program crushes due to allocating the memory.
I need your advice!

Comment: This function looks ok. The crash is elsewhere.

Comment: Please show the code where you invoke your function and how you use the result. Note that `A` is actually not a 2D-array like `int[n][m]`, but rather a pointer to an array of pointers to ints.

Comment: First of all you should check if your calls to `malloc` fail

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array and cannot represent one. If you want a 2D array, use one, there is enough material here and elsewhere, that would also simplify allocation/freeing. Also don't cast the result of `malloc`. Re your problem: provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where its crashing? inside the function? outside? + please check your malloc return value in the code

Comment: [DON'T CAST THE RETURN VALUE OF MALLOC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).